# ScrollTo function is AMP?

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I want to scroll to a specific position in AMP Page. Is there any function in AMP to scroll to some horizontal or vertical Position or is there any way to achieve this in AMP.

Comment: What do the docs say?

Comment: Scroll to top is there in docs. There is no such thing as ScrollTo specific position. I want to know if we can achieve this is AMP using css  or some other functions.

Comment: The AMP documentation has the function scrollTo() in it. Perhaps you are using a browser that is affected by the issue you have, such as Mozilla/5.0, Chrome/68, Safari/537 and others noted in this issue https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/17792

Comment: Doest it scrolls to specific (x,y) coordinate?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`scrollTo()`](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-actions-and-events/#target:-amp) target to scroll to a specific item on a page, if you provide that item's id. You can also identify if you want the item scrolled to the `top`, `center`, or `bottom` of the page.

Here is the syntax I used for `tap` action on a button.

```
  <button on="tap:AMP.scrollTo(id='scroll2me', position='center')">
    Scroll to green div
  </button>
```